# In vxworks 5.5.1 kernelInit() hangs

Tags: vxworks

I have an atom board and I am trying to build a BSP with VxWorks 5.5.1.
I have got the bootrom working wherein it loads the vxworks.st image from the hard disk (mSATA configured in IDE mode).

I am using the pcPentium4 BSP as the baseline for building the BSP. While the atom core has multiple threads, all the other APs are in INIT SIPI mode (the BIOS is EFI based but it has CSM support)

The BSP is compiled with basic PIC support (so no VIRTUAL_WIRE or SYMMETRIC_IO_MODE are enabled).

The bootElfModule() in the bootrom is passing control to the vxworks image. The usrInit() function in usrConfig.c is getting invoked.

The control gets all the way to the kernelInit() function call in usrInit() in usrConfig.c but kernelInit() hangs. I have verified that the x86 EFLAGS : IF flag is 0 before calling kernelInit(). I have also explicitly disabled all 15 IRQs by calling sysIntDisablePIC() explicitly before calling kernelInit().

The interesting this is that the same kernel works in the bootrom where is the same code to create the tBoot task (which then loads the vxworks image).

I read the appnote from WindRiver on the bootrom and it says that interrupts could be enabled when kernelInit() is invoked so I explicitly disabled all IRQs.

Any ideas on what could be going wrong?. Where can I look?.

Thanks,